# No notification when object is changed

Tags: realm

I have a class with one primary key and one indexed property.

ModelBookmark.h

```
@interface ModelBookmark : RLMObject
@property NSString *uuid;
@property NSString *folderUuid;
@end
```

ModelBookmark.m

```
@implementation ModelBookmark
+ (NSArray *)indexedProperties
{
    return @[@"folderUuid"];
}

+ (NSString *) primaryKey
{
    return @"uuid";
}

-(void) changeFolder:(NSString *)newFolderUUID
{
    if(![self.folderUuid isEqualToString:newFolderUUID])
    {
        RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
        [realm beginWriteTransaction];
        self.folderUuid = newFolderUUID;
        [realm commitWriteTransaction];
    }
}
@end
```

And in some table I want to receive notifications about all changes. I wrote:

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
__weak MyCollectionsViewController *wself = self;
_bookmarksNotificationToken = [[ModelBookmark allObjectsInRealm:realm] addNotificationBlock:^(RLMResults *results, RLMCollectionChange *change, NSError *error) {
    [wself updateFolderChilds:results change:change];
}];
```

Seems everything is good and should work. But it doesn't. When I change `folderUuid` - there is only 50% chance that i'll receive notification about change.

How could I check what's going on wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After asking a question I wrote minimal project to demonstrate this issue. And it appears that demo project just worked fine. I compared line to line with code of my application and found that this issue was caused by previous transaction, that disabled notification token for a next call.

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
// any changes there
[realm commitWriteTransactionWithoutNotifying:@[_bookmarksNotificationToken] error:nil];
```

This code disables one call of `_bookmarksNotificationToken`. No matter it will be triggered by this transaction or any other transaction in the future. And that's was unexpected. Because I thought, that list of ignored notifications is stored per transaction, while it's just a `ignore-next-N-calls` counter inside `RLMNotificationToken`.